# Xcode 11 shows a missing module error when compiling Python 3.8

Tags: python, xcode

I get this error after setting up Xcode to develop Python:

```
error: module importing failed: invalid pathname
Hello World This Is Python!
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

I created a hard link to the Python3.8 executable and this shouldn't happen, I just don't know why it happens.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

So I reread Eric Sudan's post on setting this up and found that I hadn't deselected the "Debug Executable" check box.  After doing so the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

This issue not only with python :)

```
error: module importing failed: invalid pathname
Welcome to Apple Swift version 5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51).
```

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.taskgated.90006): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /usr/libexec/taskgated, error = 108: Invalid path
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.repl_swift.90004): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/repl_swift, error = 2: No such file or directory
```

this issue in new Xcode or new swift :)